# Date format for bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Hi i am using bootstrap datepicker. I need to get the value from datepicker text box in the format like `date-month-year` to my controller but presently i am getting values like 
`Tue Oct 01 00:00:00 IST 2013`

I have tried formatting date but still i am getting same result . I have tried like below

```
$(function() {
    window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
    $('#birthday').datepicker({
        format: "DD, d MM, yy"
    })
});
```

Comment: Which datepicker are you using? There are several for Bootstrap.

Comment: jquery datepicker and even i can't use changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true options also

Comment: Can you provide a link for the plugin.. there are many datepickers.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datepicker/downloads/detail?name=jquery.datePicker.min-2.1.2.js&can=1&q=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format attribute is not working. You can try something similar to this:

```
var dt = $('#dt').datepicker({format:'dd/mm/yyyy'}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {

   var newDate = new Date(ev.date);
   var year = newDate.getFullYear();
   var month = (newDate.getMonth()+1);
   var day = newDate.getDate();

   dt.setValue(day+'-'+month+'-'+year);
   dt.hide();

}).data('datepicker');
```

You are formatting your date by yourself.
You can ignore the format attribute.